# Эксперименты с монетой (Эл Свейгарт)

Tags: python

Делаю задание, которое заключаеся вот, в чем :
Напишите программу, которая позволит узнать, насколько часто серия
из шести решек или шести орлов появляется в случайно сгенерированном
списке.
Написала код, который состоит из двух частей :
в первой части генерируется
список случайно выбранных значений орлов и решек, а во второй
части проверяется, есть ли в нем интересующая нас серия.
Вот он :

```
import random

numberOfStreaks = 0
arr = []
subArr = ["OOOOOO", "PPPPPP"]

def coinFlip(array) :
    for i in range(0, 100, 1):
        coin = random.randint(0, 1)
        if coin == 1 :
            array.append("O")
        else :
            array.append("P")
    return array

res = coinFlip(arr)

for i in subArr :
    for j in res :
        if i in j :
            numberOfStreaks = numberOfStreaks + 1

print(res)
print(numberOfStreaks)
input("\nEnter")
```

Проблема заключается в том, что у меня не получается найти количество вхождений заданного подсписка в основном списке.
Собственно проблемное место :

```
for i in subArr :
        for j in res :
            if i in j :
                numberOfStreaks = numberOfStreaks + 1
```

Пожалуйста, помогите исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

numberOfStreaks = 0
arr = []
subArr = ["OOOOOO", "PPPPPP"]

def coinFlip(array) :
    for i in range(0, 100, 1):
        coin = random.randint(0, 1)
        if coin == 1 :
            array.append("O")
        else :
            array.append("P")
    return array

res = coinFlip(arr)

sixO=0
sixR=0
nowO=0
nowR=0
for it in res:
    if it=='O':
        nowO+=1
        nowR=0
    else:
        nowR+=1
        nowO=0
    if nowO==6:
        sixO+=1
        nowO=0
    if nowR==6:
        sixR+=1
        nowR=0

print(sixR,sixO)
```

Суть решения создаём четыре счётсчика для два для текущего показателя, два для итоговых. Сравнивая каждый элемент плюсуем текущий показатиль либо орла либо решка, обнуляя показатель противоположный.
При достижении нужного количества вхождений плюсуюм результат.
Но есть загвоздка: o ooooo o должно защитаться за одно вхождение либо за два.
& я бы игрался с модулем itertools и [].count('') для более быстрого кода

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь быстрое реагирование!

Answer (score 0):

Если суммарно и тех и тех, то работает, если поменять вашу проверку на такую:

```
for i in subArr :
    for j in range(len(res)):
        if list(i) == res[j:j+6]:
            numberOfStreaks = numberOfStreaks + 1
```

Т.е. вырезаем из полученного списка 6 элементов и сравниваем их с символами элемента списка искомых последовательностей.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

задачу вы уже решили, поэтому предложу для разнообразия два чуть более "продвинутых" варианта решения:

в регулярным выражением:

```
from random import choices
from re import findall

res = choices(['O','P'], k=100)
number_of_streaks = sum(len(i)-5 for i in findall(r'O{6,}|P{6,}',''.join(res)))
```

с рекурсией:

```
from random import choices

res = ''.join(choices(['O','P'], k=100))
f = lambda x, y: 0 if (i:=x.find(y))==-1 else 1 + f(x[i+1:], y)
number_of_streaks = sum(f(res, i) for i in ['OOOOOO','PPPPPP'])
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очнь интересные варианты